# Windows snapping no longer works on 14.04.3 after upgrading to Gnome 3.12.1

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

I've installed CCSM and followed the steps mentioned in several other posts on this issue an nothing has worked. When I drag a window to the top left it just drags it off the screen instead of making it resize to take up half my monitor. I rely pretty heavier on this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to enable windows tiling in dconf editor.

select gnome > mutter:check "windows tiling"

scroll down

select shell > overrides:check "windows tiling"

close dconf editor

restart machine

worked for me.